# Java ServerSocket.accept() infinity loop without SocketTimeout or other Exception

Tags: java, serversocket

My thread always stops after several days at `serverSocket.accept()`. Due to monitoring this thread with another thread I know that the thread state is still `RUNNABLE` after this problem.

Here a snippet of my code:

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 50, addr);
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(180000); // 3 Minutes

public void run()
   {
      Socket server = null;

      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            server = serverSocket.accept(); //locks until a connection is made
         }
         catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
         {
            Util.showException(s);
            continue;
         }

      }
  }
```

The `SocketTimeoutException` will also not be thrown... btw. There is another `try/catch` around the whole `while`-loop... After it stops at `serverSocket.accept()` I get no exception.

Comment: When you say 'infinity loop ' do you mean *block*?

Comment: "btw. there is another try/catch arount the whole while-loop..." can you post your full code

Comment: it stucks on serverSocket.accept(). There is no Exception and the while-loop does not continue.

@kuhajeyan with the other try/catch i only wanted to say that i catch all Exceptions, not only SocketTimeoutException.